# View and CSS are not updated on mobile after I modify an element classlist with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, django, mobile

So for some context, I have a portfolio page with some projects which I can filter by tags.

The CSS (color) of the tags change when it's selected/deselected, by adding/removing a `selected` class to the element.

But somehow a selected tag doesn't go back to it's initial state when it's clicked a second time, even though the class list is correctly updated.

This happens only on mobile (I could test on Android and iOS), the behavior is the one expected on desktop.

The page is rendered with Django, and the HTML and JavaScript look like this:

```
{% extends './base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Pierre Bonneau - Portfolio{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
<main class="container flex-shrink-0">
    <!-- TAGS -->
    <div class="tag-list text-center">
        <ul>
            <li class="project-tag selected" data-filter="All">All</li>
            {% for tag in tags %}
            <li class="project-tag" data-filter="{{tag.name}}">{{tag.name}}</li>
            {%endfor%}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- GALERY -->
    <div class="project-grid">
        {% for project in project_list %}
        <div class="project-card" data-tags="{%for tag in project.tags.all%}{{tag.name}}, {%endfor%}">
            <img src="{{ project.thumbnail.url }}" class="img-fluid w-100 h-100"
                alt="{{ project.project_name }} thumbnail">
            <div class="project-text">
                <a href="{{project.gitlab_link}}">
                    <h4>{{project.project_name}}</h5>
                        <p>{{project.description}}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
    </div>
    <div id="no-project" class="hidden">There is no project of this type.</div>
</main>

{% endblock content %}

{%block scripts%}
<script>
    let tags = document.querySelectorAll('.project-tag');
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.project-card');

    for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        tags[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            let dataFilter = this.getAttribute('data-filter');
            if (dataFilter == 'All') {
                for (let j = 0; j < tags.length; j++) {
                    tags[j].classList.remove('selected');
                }
                this.classList.add('selected');
            } else if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
                this.classList.remove('selected');
                if (document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length == 0) {
                    all_tag = document.querySelector("li[data-filter='All']");
                    all_tag.classList.add('selected');
                }
            } else {
                all_tag = document.querySelector("li[data-filter='All']");
                all_tag.classList.remove('selected');
                this.classList.add('selected');
            }

            let selectedTags = [];
            document.querySelectorAll('.selected').forEach(function (tag) {
                selectedTags.push(tag.getAttribute('data-filter'));
            });

            for (let k = 0; k < items.length; k++) {
                if (selectedTags[0] == 'All') {
                    items[k].classList.remove('hidden');
                } else {
                    itemTags = items[k].getAttribute('data-tags').split(", ");
                    display = selectedTags.every(t => itemTags.includes(t));
                    if (display) {
                        items[k].classList.remove('hidden');
                    } else {
                        items[k].classList.add('hidden');
                    }
                }
            }

            let noProject = document.getElementById('no-project')
            if (document.querySelectorAll('.project-card:not(.hidden)').length == 0) {
                noProject.classList.remove('hidden');
            } else {
                noProject.classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }
        )
    }
</script>
{%endblock scripts%}
```

I have the website address as it's already hosted, but don't know if I can post it here.

Would you have any hint at why the view is not updated the same way on mobile and desktop when classList is changed ?